# Regular expression matching unescaped paired brackets and nested function calls

Tags: php, regex, templating

Here's the problem: given a string like

```
"<p>The price for vehicles {capitalize(pluralize(vehicle))} is {format_number(value, language)}</p><span>{employee_name}</span><span>\{do not parse me}</span>"
```

I need (1) a regex pattern in PHP that matches all values between un-escaped pairs of curly brackets and (2) another regex pattern that matches function calls and nested function calls *(once the first pattern is matched)*. Of course, if I could use one regex only for both tasks that would be awesome.

By the way, I can't use Smarty, Twig or any other library - that's the only reason I have to build a parsing mechanism myself.

Thanks a ton!

**Solution**
(1) A partial solution for the first problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258143/get-all-nested-curly-braces). Basically, we use the regex

```
(?={((?:[^{}]++|{(?1)})++)})
```

and find the matches at index 1 of the resulting array.

It's partial because I still need to find a way of ignoring escaped braces, though.

(2) I'm considering the use of recursive regex, as suggested by Mario. Will post result here.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: The first regex is easy, but the second one can't be done using PHP. You will have to use a parser instead.

Comment: Regular expressions are not a good choice for parsing nested / recursive structures.

Comment: You can use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\\\\)` for eschewing escaped curlys, and a [`(?R)` recursive regex](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) if you want to assert proper function nesting.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I found a way to solve (1) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258143/get-all-nested-curly-braces). I still haven't been successful with (2).

Comment: @mario I didn't know that there is anther language than .NET that supports nested structures, +1 for that.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/uI4qN0) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jerry - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn I just wanted to make sure that this is what OP required, but they didn't revert back... I try to avoid instances where OP has one problem which turns out to be a completely different problem ^^ You can keep your answer :)

Comment: @Jerry - Completely understood. I just found myself re-attempting to solve the regex before noticing your comment. Not to mention, your solution appears to solve the OP's needs by my reading as well - may as well flag as a viable answer candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

This appears to be what you're looking for:

```
(?<!\\){([^(){}]+)\(((?:[^(){}]+|\(((?2))\))*)\)}
```

Link: http://www.regex101.com/r/uI4qN0

~ answer per [Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578604/jerry)

Note: For comparison - simply ignoring escaped braces is accomplished by adding a negative lookahead `(?<!\\)` to the beginning of the expression, like so:

```
(?<!\\)(?={((?:[^{}]++|{(?1)})++)})
```